# RefTex in emacs menu bar

Tags: emacs23

I would be very grateful if anyone can give advice on creating a Ref menu in the menu bar in GNU emacs.

Q: How do I get RefTeX to create a Ref menu in the menu bar in emacs? Or is this possible on windows? The RefTeX manual says "on systems which support this", but it does not indicate which systems. Previously I have been working on a Mac OSX, using Aquamacs and have this ref in the menubar.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Aside: Windows 7, emacs version 23.1, AUCTeX, LaTeX installed.

I have inserted the following into my .emacs file (I got this code from EmacsWiki and changed the path):

```
(require 'tex-site)
(autoload 'reftex-mode "reftex" "RefTeX Minor Mode" t)
(autoload 'turn-on-reftex "reftex" "RefTeX Minor Mode" nil)
(autoload 'reftex-citation "reftex-cite" "Make citation" nil)
(autoload 'reftex-index-phrase-mode "reftex-index" "Phrase Mode" t)
(add-hook 'latex-mode-hook 'turn-on-reftex) ; with Emacs latex mode
;; (add-hook 'reftex-load-hook 'imenu-add-menubar-index)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook '(lambda () (require 'latex-units)
                      (turn-on-reftex)
                      (turn-on-auto-fill)
                      (LaTeX-math-mode)
                      (load "preview-latex.el" nil t t)))

(setq LaTeX-eqnarray-label "eq"
      LaTeX-equation-label "eq"
      LaTeX-figure-label "fig"
      LaTeX-table-label "tab"
      TeX-auto-save t
      TeX-newline-function 'reindent-then-newline-and-indent
      TeX-parse-self t
      TeX-style-path
      '("style/" "auto/"
        "C:/emacs/emacs-23.3/site-lisp/auctex/style/"
        "C:/emacs/emacs-23.3/var/auctex/"
        "C:/emacs/emacs-23.3/site-lisp/auctex/style/")
      LaTeX-section-hook
      '(LaTeX-section-heading
  LaTeX-section-title
      LaTeX-section-toc
      LaTeX-section-section
      LaTeX-section-label))

(setq reftex-cite-format 'natbib
      reftex-default-bibliography
      '("~/Desktop/References/MyLibrary.bib")
      reftex-extra-bindings t
      reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t
      reftex-sort-bibtex-matches 'year
      reftex-toc-mode-hook nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.... but I solved it by inserting the lines below into my site-start.el

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (turn-on-reftex)
        (setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t)))

This placed a 'Ref' menu in the toolbar.

For further RefTex customizations, I have put these in my .emacs file

HTH

Erica